# Strategy on implementing a Shopping Cart with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to implement and API . In this API the user has the classic shopping cart. I want to have this shopping cart stored for each user, so when for example he exits/logout  from the application , the shopping cart is saved , and thus restored when he login again.

My current implementation is a table with User ID's as a column , and then the columns that have to do with what the shopping cart contains. But I think that this implementation is not good , because when a lot of users are in the platform , then a big search must happen to the table in order to obtain the correct shopping cart for the user, and it will be slow.

An other idea that I have is to make a table dynamic for each user with just one row (with many columns) that will be created for this only user only, in a way that each user will have this dynamically created table and will have quick access to it .

Questions:
1) Can I implement this idea in MySQL
2) Can you suggest a better strategy ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

i have not worked on large e-com websites but i have implemented cart system with MySQL for many times, your approach is good if you want to do some machine learning with cart data.

i use to delete data after some time interval (a week, a month) days if user has not checkout using cronjob.

Or

Send email to the user for checkout, if user done the same then okay else delete the data.

Note:- This is just a suggestion.